# Подключение двух мониторов к ноутбуку

Tags: устройства, ноутбук

Всем привет! Хочу подключить два абсолютно одинаковых монитора к ноутбуку, ноутбук Lenovo Y470, на ноутбуке есть два разъема HDMI и VGA, мониторы вот эти LG 19 Flatron E1942C-BN, у этого моника скорее всего только VGA разъем. Подскажите, пожалуйста, получится ли подключить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если интересует возможность работы двух дополнительных мониторов - то вполне возможно, надо смотреть на железке...

Если интересует как подключить VGA-моник к HDMI-порту - то можно использовать, например, [ЭТО](http://www.brilliantstore.com/hdmi_cables_dekcell_cpa_1369.html).

Comment: больше интересует конечно что сразу два моника работали

Comment: Ну... Дальше только "метод научного тыка"....:) Возможно, придется поиграЦЦо с BIOS, возможно - с настройками дров. Допускаю, что монитор, собственно, лаптопа может отрубиться автоматом при подключении одного из дополнительных мониторов. Так же допускаю, что один из сигналов "наружу" может просто дублировать основной монитор.Пробовать, пробовать и еще раз пробовать!!! В конце концов - "дорогу осилит идущий"(с).

Comment: Интересно, чем все-таки закончился сабж? Получилось?

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего никак. Работать будет только один+ монитор самого ноутбука.

т.к.  это стандартные настройки.

Comment: похоже, что на моем ноуте VGA отсносится ко встроенному видео, а HDMI к дискретной карте

Answer (score 0):

можно с VGA SPLITTER